# chapter navigation in video with video.js?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js

I am new to video.js framework. I have video.js setup and able to run video with subtitles and captions.My question is how to add chapter navigation to my video?. I tried with track kind="chapters" but no use. Can any one help to add chapter navigation to my video.
Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0):

I used video.js 4.10.0 instead of video.js 4.12.5 version. It work's cool...